# Lectora Chinese characters that are manipulated using Variables are not coming in UTF-8

Tags: chinese-locale

In lectora Inspire V11, while doing chinese course all Traditional Chinese characters that are directly assigned are coming in UTF 8  properly. Only the variables that are manipulated are not coming in UTF-8 there by resulting in Junk characters. Does anybody have any work around?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably better off asking for help at Lectora's community website, https://community.trivantis.com/connect/